# How can I use a string with slash in URI query parameters?

Tags: flutter, url, uri

I have a `URI` like this:

```dart
Uri(
  scheme: 'https',
  host: 'host.com',
  path: '/path',
  queryParameters: <String, String>{
    'callback_uri': 'schema://another_path',
  },
);
```

but when I want to open it `URL` becomes to:

```
https://host.com/path?callback_uri=schema%253A%252F%252Fanother_path
```

how can I use such `queryParameters` in the `URI` class?

Answer (score 1):

Your double(`//`) slash converts into `%253A%252F%252`, all symbols in query parameter just encoded into a string.

You get the original path URL by decoding this

```
void main() {
  var data = Uri(
    scheme: 'https',
    host: 'host.com',
    path: '/path',
    queryParameters: <String, String>{
      'callback_uri': 'schema://another_path',
    },
  );

  print(Uri.decodeFull(data.toString())); //https://host.com/path?callback_uri=schema://another_path

}
```

Comment: I know that, how can I prevent it?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I already checked it, it doesn't work for me because the widget I am using needs `URI` directly.

Comment: Can you share widget code?